# How to install the fitsio package in python

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am trying to install the fitsio package to python. I have tried so using pip, but that resulted in the following error: "ValueError: could not configure cfitsio 3370". I have also tried to install it without pip, but it gave me the same error. Any advise on how to install it properly? I don't have a lot of python experience, so please keep it simple. Thanks!

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @koukouviou windows 8.1 . I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that

Comment: Are you trying to run pip in the cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the setup.py [source code](https://github.com/esheldon/fitsio/blob/master/setup.py) of the python fitsio package, the package is configured and compiled using `os.system('sh ./configure')` (line 40)  and `os.system('make')` (line 47) respectively. This is expected since the python fitsio package is basically a python wrapper of the C version of the fitsio library.

These are Linux commands, which you are trying to run natively at the Windows Command Prompt. This can't work and that's why you get the errors you're getting.

To get the python `fitsio` package installed on Windows you need to use something like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). Be sure to include the `make` and `gcc` in the packages you install in Cygwin (they are usually installed by default), as the fitsio package you want requires a [GNU Toolchain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_toolchain) for compiling the `cfitsio`. Another option would be to switch to Linux or use a Linux virtual machine but that's going a long way just to get a library to work :)

After installing the package you can find some examples for the `fitsio` module in python at the [github repository](https://github.com/esheldon/fitsio/) landing page of the package.